# Crashes are not getting logged : React native Firebase - Crashlytics ( Android)

Tags: android, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

- React native version : 0.59
- react-native-firebase": "^5.5.0",

I'm able to log crashes with iOS but in Android its not getting logged in crashlytics dashboard.
I followed the official documentation but it didn't work.
Please share the steps or solution if anyone has done this for React-native-Android.

Below is my device log saying :**Crashlytics build id is missing**
[image]

Here is my android/app/build.gradle

[image]

and here is my android/build.gradle
[image]